# Events ID 4013 For DNS and 1844 for Active Directory

Tags: dns, windows-server-2008, active-directory

i have newly register a virtual private server (windows 2008 R2), my problem is when i install an Active Directory and DNS Roles its raise the below events IDs 4013 For DNS and 1844 for Active Directory, what i understand from errors that the DNS cant start before the active directory finish synchronization, any one can help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seeing event 4013 is normal for a single-DC domain. Seeing both events is also normal in multi-DC environments when you are restarting a DC (say DC1) and another DC that is configured as DC1's Primary DNS server is not accessible. See detailed explanation of these events: [4013](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2001093), [1844](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd941854(v=ws.10).aspx)